# Letting user add their location on interactive map

Tags: openstreetmap

I would like to know if it is possible to create an interactive map where the user will be allowed to add their own location to the map (I would use OSM as the basemap) and then calculate the distance between that location and some other objects that the map shows?

If it is possible, can you explain to me the basic idea how it could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer reside on the several sources. First you must create an html code to get the user location. It can be an html form/input (doc [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)). You can also use a locator (go [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/mobile-jq.html#mappage) and choose locate) .
This location you store it in a OpenLayers.LonLat (doc [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/.../LonLat-js.html)), and you use it to draw the point as an Openlayers.Marker (doc [enter link description here](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Marker-js.html)).
Then you need the other point to hich to compute the distance.
The distance computing can be done like [here](http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL27/examples/shortestDistance.asp).